# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 104 Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, networking

```
9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 104  Connection reset by peer
[9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
[9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
[9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
[9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:705)
[9/6/15 5:11:12:539 UTC] 00000040 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
```

This is the exception i am getting when my service provider makes a failover. Here my service provider Who has the server architecture as below

One GSLB followed by LLB1 and LLB2. LLB1 is connected to server 1,2,3 and LLB2 is connected to server 4,5,6.

They are making LLB1 down and redirecting all incoming request to LLB2. But the connection already make by us in LLB1 are experiencing the above exception. We asked the service provider, but they said that other consumers are not experiencing this issue. I am not sure even though we have stateless objects in transaction why this is happening.

If we restart our application server that are consuming this service then all the requests are going to LLB2 as expected by both the end.